# Onlyoffice or WOPI protocol

Tags: ms-office, integration, ms-wopi, onlyoffice

I'm looking for a MS Office editor API for my web app to enable users to upload/create word or excel documents, edit them and save them online. I found Onlyoffice and WOPI protocol can provide this but I'm not sure which one works better or easier to develop. I appreciate if you can share your experience.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you use Docker version Community Server to provide the service. Your web app can open webview with url point to the Community Server.

```
git clone https://github.com/ONLYOFFICE/Docker-CommunityServer.git
```

Edit docker-compose.workspace.yml and remove all mail stuff if you don't need mails like me.

```
# Start
docker-compose -f docker-compose.workspace.yml up -d
# Open browser to localhost

# Stop
docker-compose -f docker-compose.workspace.yml down
# Stop and delete volume data
docker-compose -f docker-compose.workspace.yml down -v
```